# Adding multiple child entities to a parent entity when creating the parent entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a form on a page to add a Post (parent), before submitting the form, a user should be able to add 1 or more Sections (children) to the Post.

The form:

```
        <form asp-action="AddSection">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-controller="Post" asp-action="AddPost" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Post" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SectionTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SectionTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SectionTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SectionDescription" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SectionDescription" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SectionDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button id="add-section-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Section</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

AddPostViewModel

```
public class AddPostViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string SectionTitle { get; set; }
        public string SectionDescription { get; set; }

        public static List<Section> Sections { get; set; } = new List<Section>();
    }
```

AddPost (GET)

```
        public IActionResult AddPost()
        {
            var viewModel = new AddPostViewModel();

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

AddSection(POST via Ajax)

```
public IActionResult AddSection(AddPostViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var section = new Section()
            {
                Title = viewModel.SectionTitle,
                Description = viewModel.SectionDescription
            };

            AddPostViewModel.Sections.Add(section);

            var pendingSection = new PendingSectionViewModel()
            {
                Title = viewModel.SectionTitle,
                Description = viewModel.SectionDescription,
            };

            return ViewComponent("PendingSections", new { section = pendingSection });
        }
```

AddPost (POST)

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddPost(AddPostViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var post = new Post()
            {
                Title = viewModel.Title,
                Description = viewModel.Description,
                Sections = AddPostViewModel.Sections
            };

            _db.Add(post);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

This code works and writes to database as intended, a parent is written with it's associated children. However the code is messy and I plan to refactor anyway but what would be a better way of approaching this?

Quick note on AddSection too. The reason it returns a ViewComponent is it's used to feedback to the user what sections they have added to their post and will have the ability to edit/delete them later down the line. The added sections are added to the top of the page in a list.